Segmentation fault - boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run()
I have a simple class that handles execution of a callback function on another thread, with a delay, using boost::asio.
The delay can be reset, so the class can also work like a watchdog.
The class works, however every so often (~10% of the time), it crashes with a SIGSEGV on class destruction. I can't seem to figure out why. My first though was that maybe this is no longer valid (as noticed by the this=0x0 in the error trace) but since we're waiting on the thread to join before finishing destroying the class, it should be valid for the whole duration. Or am I mission something?
Thanks for all the help!
Below is the class .cpp code & GDB stack trace. Variable types are as follows.
boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds delay_ms_;
boost::asio::io_context io_;
boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
boost::thread thread_;
std::mutex mutable mutex_;
bool is_running = false;

AsyncExecutor::AsyncExecutor(std::chrono::milliseconds const &delay_ms, Callback callback) :
    delay_ms_(delay_ms),
    callback_(callback),
    io_(),
    timer_(io_, delay_ms_)
{
}

AsyncExecutor::~AsyncExecutor() {

    // Make sure the timer stops when the object is destroyed & callback is not called.
    stop();
}

void AsyncExecutor::start() {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (is_running)
        return;
    
    is_running = true;

    if (io_.stopped()) {
        io_.reset(); // Reset io_service if it has stopped
    }

    timer_.expires_after(delay_ms_);
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&AsyncExecutor::timer_ran, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    // Start the io context in a separate thread.
    // Once the timer fires, the thread will exit.
    thread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_));
}

void AsyncExecutor::stop() {

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!is_running)
            return;

        // Cancel the timer.
        boost::asio::post(io_, [this]() {
            this->timer_.cancel();
        });
    }

    // Finaly wait for the thread to finish.
    if (this->thread_.joinable())
        this->thread_.join();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);    
    is_running = false;
}

void AsyncExecutor::reset() {

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (!is_running)
        return;

    // Reset the timer.
    boost::asio::post(io_, [this]() {
        this->timer_.expires_after(this->delay_ms_);
        this->timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&AsyncExecutor::timer_ran, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    });
}

void AsyncExecutor::timer_ran(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        is_running = false;
    }
    
    // If the timer was cancelled, we don't want to execute the callback or detach the thread.
    // Reset also calls this function with ec, so we want to keep the thread attached.
    // This complicates things & means that join() must be called in stop() to wait for the thread to finish.
    // But if the thread fires the callback, it will detach itself.
    if (ec) {
        return;
    }

    if (this->callback_)
        this->callback_();
        
    io_.stop();

    // Detach the thread, as it is no longer needed. It will be cleaned up by the OS.
    this->thread_.detach();
}

bool AsyncExecutor::is_timer_running() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return is_running;
}


[gdb-7] [New Thread 0x7fff1a7fc000 (LWP 385144)]
[gdb-7] [Thread 0x7fff1a7fc000 (LWP 385075) exited]
[gdb-7] 
[gdb-7] Thread 171 "scout_control_u" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[gdb-7] [Switching to Thread 0x7fff2253c000 (LWP 385067)]
[gdb-7] boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run (this=0x0, usec=<optimized out>, ops=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:462
[gdb-7] 462     if (timer_fd_ == -1)
[gdb-7] #0  boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(long, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation>&)
[gdb-7]     (this=0x0, usec=<optimized out>, ops=...)
[gdb-7]     at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:462
[gdb-7] #1  0x00007ffff6f0aef3 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&)
[gdb-7]     (this=this@entry=0x7fff1412e5f0, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...)
[gdb-7]     at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:465
[gdb-7] #2  0x00007ffff6f0bb01 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) (this=0x7fff1412e5f0, ec=...)
[gdb-7]     at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:204
[gdb-7] #3  0x00007ffff6f0d552 in boost::asio::io_context::run() (this=<optimized out>)
[gdb-7]     at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_context.ipp:63
[gdb-7] #4  0x00007ffff1f570cb in  ()
[gdb-7]     at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.74.0
[gdb-7] #5  0x00007ffff7094ac3 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>)
[gdb-7]     at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442
[gdb-7] #6  0x00007ffff7126850 in clone3 ()
[gdb-7]     at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:81

I was expecting the class to cancel the background task & not throw.

I don't think the problem is your thread. You seem to be using the global io_context anyway, so things don't necessarily happen on your thread, and you keeping pushing things onto it with a captured this without any protection. I'm too lazy to try and figure out all possible execution paths, plus not knowing the rest of your code; it's just too confusing -- it would be generally easier if you would wrap this into a shared_ptr and capture shared_ptr or weak_ptr depending on what you need, to ensure everything stays safe no matter what.

You're mixing io_service (!?) with io_context, using boost::thread instead of std::thread, using a full blown mutex to synchronize on a bool (make it atomic?) that is redundant since the timer knows everything that it needs to know. And with all that, reset() and stop() invoke Undefined Behaviour because steady_timer instances are not thread-safe.
You're joining and detaching the thread for little reason (there's never a reason not to join it here). All in all you're basically implementing a very expensive version of
void on_timeout(Duration d, Callback cb) {
    std::thread{[d, cb] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
        cb();
    }}.detach();
}

With perhaps the only extra feature of postponing it by calling reset() while it is still waiting. Consider not worrying about the thread at all:
struct AsyncExecutor {
    using Timer = asio::steady_timer;

    AsyncExecutor(Duration delay_ms, Callback callback) : delay_ms_(delay_ms), callback_(callback) {}

    ~AsyncExecutor() {
        trace("~dtor()");
        auto f = timer_.async_wait(asio::use_future);
        do_stop();
        f.wait(); // ensure the timer is done
    }

    void start() { trace("start()"); do_start(false); }
    void reset() { trace("reset()"); do_start(true);  }
    void stop()  { trace("stop()");  do_stop();       }

  private:
    static constexpr Timer::time_point STOPPED = Timer::time_point::min();

    asio::steady_timer timer_{make_strand(asio::system_executor{}), STOPPED};
    Duration           delay_ms_;
    Callback           callback_;

    void do_start(bool require_running) {
        dispatch(timer_.get_executor(), [this, require_running] {
            if (require_running == (timer_.expiry() != STOPPED)) {
                auto num_canceled = timer_.expires_after(delay_ms_);
                trace("  [setting delay, canceled " + std::to_string(num_canceled) + "]");
                timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&AsyncExecutor::timer_ran, this, _1));
            }
        });
    }

    std::future<size_t> do_stop() {
        return dispatch(timer_.get_executor(),
                        asio::use_future([this] { return timer_.expires_at(STOPPED); }));
    }

    void timer_ran(boost::system::error_code ec) {
        trace("  [timer_ran: " + ec.message() + "]");
        if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            timer_.expires_at(STOPPED);
            if (callback_)
                callback_();
        }
    }
};

Note that all operations except construction/destruction are thread safe.
Demo program:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fmt/core.h>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

using Callback = std::function<void()>;
using Duration = asio::steady_timer::duration;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace { // logging
    constexpr auto now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    auto           start = now();

    void trace(std::string const& msg) { fmt::print("at {:4}ms {}\n", (now() - start) / 1ms, msg); }
} // namespace

struct AsyncExecutor {
    using Timer = asio::steady_timer;

    AsyncExecutor(Duration delay_ms, Callback callback) : delay_ms_(delay_ms), callback_(callback) {}

    ~AsyncExecutor() {
        trace("~dtor()");
        auto f = timer_.async_wait(asio::use_future);
        do_stop();
        f.wait(); // ensure the timer is done
    }

    void start() { trace("start()"); do_start(false); }
    void reset() { trace("reset()"); do_start(true);  }
    void stop()  { trace("stop()");  do_stop();       }

  private:
    static constexpr Timer::time_point STOPPED = Timer::time_point::min();

    asio::steady_timer timer_{make_strand(asio::system_executor{}), STOPPED};
    Duration           delay_ms_;
    Callback           callback_;

    void do_start(bool require_running) {
        dispatch(timer_.get_executor(), [this, require_running] {
            if (require_running == (timer_.expiry() != STOPPED)) {
                auto num_canceled = timer_.expires_after(delay_ms_);
                trace("  [setting delay, canceled " + std::to_string(num_canceled) + "]");
                timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&AsyncExecutor::timer_ran, this, _1));
            }
        });
    }

    std::future<size_t> do_stop() {
        return dispatch(timer_.get_executor(),
                        asio::use_future([this] { return timer_.expires_at(STOPPED); }));
    }

    void timer_ran(boost::system::error_code ec) {
        trace("  [timer_ran: " + ec.message() + "]");
        if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            timer_.expires_at(STOPPED);
            if (callback_)
                callback_();
        }
    }
};

using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
int main() {
    {
        trace("--- Main started");
        AsyncExecutor job(1500ms, [] {trace("~~~RUNNING TIMED JOB~~~"); });

        sleep_for(500ms);
        job.reset(); // no effect, not pending
        job.start();

        sleep_for(200ms);
        job.start(); // no effect, already pending

        trace("--- Main keeping the job alive");
        for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            job.reset(); // restarts the wait of 1500ms
            sleep_for(1.0s);
        }
        trace("--- Main loop done");

        sleep_for(1.0s); // this allows job to run

        job.reset(); // no effect, not pending
        job.start();

        sleep_for(200ms);
    } // destructor cancels the job
    trace("--- Main exit");
}

Printing e.g.:


This is all good, however I can't have main thread blocked for any time. I figured out what went wrong with my example above. See answer. But I will rewrite with atomic bool.

Nobody is having the main thread blocked.

Oh, you're right. My bad, I didn't see correctly. Your solution is much better, yea. Thank you for the help!

The problem was with the order of execution in timer_ran()
This is the correct version:
if (ec) {
    return;
}

io_.stop();

if (this->callback_)
    this->callback_();

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    is_running = false;
}

// Detach the thread, as it is no longer needed. It will be cleaned up by the OS.
this->thread_.detach();

