boost asio: how to encapsulate strand properly
The design I want seems like fairly basic:
struct my_object {
  explicit my_object(io_context& ctx)
   : strand{make_strand(ctx)} 
  {
     socket = make_unique<some_socket_like_object>(*strand);
  } 

  void my_api() { 
   // Various async operations are launched through the socket
   // which end up on the strand. They use some_data, this, etc.
  }

  ~my_object() { 
    // finish all outstanding async operations that 
    // may access "some_data", "this" etc.
 
    // delete the strand 
    strand.reset();
  }

private:
  // my class's data:
  unique_ptr<socket> socket;
  data some_data;
  cancellation_signal some_cancellation;
  // etc...

  // strand will be deleted first
  optional<strand<...>> strand;
};

What is a completely run-of-the mill behaviour in any async framework seems like an absolutely infeasible design with asio and I struggle to understand why it seems to fight so hard against the concept of encapsulation.
Even with doing things such as this in the dtor:
std::future<void> wait = boost::asio::dispatch(
  boost::asio::bind_executor(
    *m_strand
  , std::packaged_task<void()>([] { /* cleanup */; }) 
  )
); 
wait.get();

and putting the strand in a std::optional to control its deletion time explicitly, I still get tasks or completion handlers running in my io_context and referencing said strand after it and all the objects putting work on it were deleted:
~my_object() { 
  std::future<void> wait = boost::asio::dispatch(
    boost::asio::bind_executor(
      *m_strand
    , std::packaged_task<void()>([this] { 
        // cleanup
        socket.reset(); 
        some_cancellation.emit(boost::asio::cancellation_type::all);
      }) 
    )
  ); 
  
  // Make sure that we get to a point where the socket object has been deleted and cannot submit new tasks ever: 
  wait.get();

  // Make sure that the strand gets cleared
  m_strand.reset(); 

  // Here the io_context still has some tasks running that were put on the strand, accessing for instance !
}

e.g. later on:
    #0 0x8010e64 in boost::asio::cancellation_slot::clear() /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/impl/cancellation_signal.ipp:42:24
    #1 0x8118d48 in void async_mqtt5::detail::cancellable_handler<boost::asio::detail::as_tuple_handler<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost::asio::any_io_executor, std::tuple<boost::system::error_code, std::vector<async_mqtt5::reason_code, std::allocator<async_mqtt5:2
    #2 0x8118d48 in async_mqtt5::detail::subscribe_op<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>, boost::asio::detail::as_tuple_handler<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost:2
    #3 0x8118238 in async_mqtt5::detail::subscribe_op<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>, boost::asio::detail::as_tuple_handler<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost:1
    #4 0x8117b44 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::subscribe_op<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>, boost::asio::detail::as_tuple_handler<boo5
    #5 0x8117b44 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::subscribe_op<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>, boost::asio::detail::as_tuple_handler<boo1
    #6 0x8117b44 in void boost::asio::detail::any_completion_handler_impl<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::subscribe_op<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::mono5
    #7 0x804d374 in boost::asio::detail::any_completion_handler_call_fn<void (boost::system::error_code)>::call(boost::asio::detail::any_completion_handler_impl_base*, boost::system::error_code) const /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/a5
    #8 0x804d374 in decltype((*this).fn_table_->call((*this).impl_, static_cast<boost::system::error_code&>(fp))) boost::asio::any_completion_handler<void (boost::system::error_code)>::operator()<boost::system::error_code&>(boost::system::error_code&) /home/jcelerier/ossia/sc5
    #9 0x8044fe8 in async_mqtt5::detail::write_req::complete(boost::system::error_code) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/async-mqtt5/include/async_mqtt5/impl/async_sender.hpp:47:3
    #10 0x8044fe8 in async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>::operator()(std::vector<async_mqtt5::detail::write_req, boost::asio::recycling_all7
    #11 0x80449b8 in void std::__invoke_impl<void, async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>&, std::vector<async_mqtt5::detail::write_req, boost:4
    #12 0x80439c0 in std::__invoke_result<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>&, std::vector<async_mqtt5::detail::write_req, boost::asio::re4
    #13 0x80439c0 in std::__invoke_result<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>&, std::vector<async_mqtt5::detail::write_req, boost::asio::re1
    #14 0x80439c0 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<std::reference_wrapper<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>>, std::vector<asy5
    #15 0x80439c0 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<std::reference_wrapper<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>>, std::vector<asy1
    #16 0x80439c0 in boost::asio::result_of<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<std::reference_wrapper<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, std::monostate>>2
    #17 0x80439c0 in boost::asio::result_of<boost::asio::executor_binder<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<std::reference_wrapper<async_mqtt5::detail::async_sender<async_mqtt5::detail::client_service<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_i2
    #18 0x80439c0 in async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stream_context<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::a3
    #19 0x80439c0 in async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stream_context<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::ap
    #20 0x80b6720 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stream_context<boost::asio::basic_st5
    #21 0x80b6aa4 in void boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stream_context<boost::asio::basic_st1
    #22 0x80b6aa4 in boost::asio::detail::binder0<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stream_conte5
    #23 0x80b6aa4 in void boost::asio::detail::executor_function::complete<boost::asio::detail::binder0<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asi7
    #24 0x786aa84 in boost::asio::detail::executor_function::operator()() /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp:61:7
    #25 0x786aa84 in void boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::do_execute<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 4ul> const, boost::asio::detail::executor_function, std::allocator<void>>(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::detail::strand_executor5
    #26 0x786a700 in void boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::execute<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 4ul> const, boost::asio::detail::executor_function>(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::strand_impl> co0
    #27 0x786a700 in boost::asio::constraint<traits::execute_member<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 4ul> const&, boost::asio::detail::executor_function>::is_valid, void>::type boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<5
    #28 0x786a700 in void boost::asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::execute_ex<boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 4ul>>>(boost::asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base const&, boost::asio::detail::executor_functi8
    #29 0x80b5eac in void boost::asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::execute<boost::asio::detail::binder0<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, 9
    #30 0x80b5aac in boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>, async_mqtt5::detail::stre5
    #31 0x80b7160 in void boost::asio::detail::executor_function::complete<boost::asio::detail::work_dispatcher<boost::asio::detail::prepend_handler<async_mqtt5::detail::write_op<async_mqtt5::detail::autoconnect_stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, bo7
    #32 0x3a8a290 in boost::asio::detail::executor_function::operator()() /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp:61:7
    #33 0x3a8a290 in boost::asio::detail::executor_op<boost::asio::detail::executor_function, std::allocator<void>, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation>::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/7
    #34 0x7866a14 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::complete(void*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_operation.hpp:40:5
    #35 0x7866a14 in boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::run_ready_handlers(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::strand_impl>&) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_executor_servic8
    #36 0x78680d0 in boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::invoker<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0ul> const, void>::operator()() /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/strand_exec5
    #37 0x78680d0 in boost::asio::detail::executor_op<boost::asio::detail::strand_executor_service::invoker<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0ul> const, void>, boost::asio::detail::recycling_allocator<void, boost::asio::detail::thread_info_ba7
    #38 0x2b5ca68 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::complete(void*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_operation.hpp:40:5
    #39 0x2b5ca68 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/b2
    #40 0x2b5bdf8 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:210:10
    #41 0x2b5f844 in boost::asio::io_context::run() /home/jcelerier/ossia/score/3rdparty/libossia/3rdparty/boost_1_85_0/boost/asio/impl/io_context.ipp:64:24

What must I do to make sure all the tasks are all completely processed and will never put any new task on the io_context at some point in my dtor ?
Adding another future to wait seems to fix my immediate crash seems to work, but how can I have any assureance that this is a correct fix, and why isn't there any proper built-in solution into asio? e.g. how can I make sure that there won't be any more thing being posted recursively on the strand as the result of various completion handlers which may not be in my control doing their thing?
wait.get();

std::future<void> wait2 = boost::asio::dispatch(*m_strand, boost::asio::use_future);
wait2.get();

m_strand.reset();


a propos of nothing, I found that dispatch(ex, asio::use_future([] { return 42; })).get() is a much nicer way to write that packaged task

I sense a confusion around executors. What do you think m_strand.reset() accomplishes?
Strands are executors. Executors are cheap value-types that conceptually hold a reference to an execution context (with potentially addditional execution behavior encoded in the type).
Therefore, copying executors is like copying references: it has no effect. The same thing goes, by implication, for the destructor.

One notable side effect could be work tracking, e.g. using require(ex, outstanding_work.tracked). Your example doesn't use that, and I tend to think that technique only makes sense inside the library internals.

So, instead here is what I would consider run-of-the-mill:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

using data = std::array<char, 1024>;

struct my_object {
    using socket_type   = tcp::socket;
    using executor_type = socket_type::executor_type;

    explicit my_object(auto ex) : socket_(make_strand(ex)) {}

    void my_api() {
        post(socket_.get_executor(), //
             asio::bind_cancellation_slot(some_cancellation.slot(), [this] {
                 for (auto& ch : some_data)
                     ch += 1;
             }));
    }

    executor_type get_executor() { return socket_.get_executor(); }
  private:
    socket_type               socket_;
    data                      some_data;
    asio::cancellation_signal some_cancellation;
};

Now, since the context isn't owned by this object, it stands to reason that it's the caller's responsibility to ensure its lifetime. Your problem is the lifetime of my_object instances.
Usually your API has some guarantees about completion of async operations (e.g. guaranteed completion). If you don't have such a guarantee (e.g. because you post detached work without a completion handler as in your example my_api), you should flip it around: Keep my_object alive as long as the work still needs to complete. The most common method is shared_from_this.

Note that dynamically allocating my_object has the side-effect of already making socket_ reference-stable, which may or may not have been a reason for you to employ unique_ptr there? I'm just guessing here because it seems contradictory that no such concern existed for some_data.

The change is very minor:
struct my_object : /*public*/  std::enable_shared_from_this<my_object> {
    using socket_type   = tcp::socket;
    using executor_type = socket_type::executor_type;

    explicit my_object(auto ex) : socket_(make_strand(ex)) {}

    void my_api() {
        post(socket_.get_executor(), //
             asio::bind_cancellation_slot(some_cancellation.slot(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
                 for (auto& ch : some_data)
                     ch += 1;
             }));
    }

    executor_type get_executor() { return socket_.get_executor(); }
  private:
    socket_type               socket_;
    data                      some_data;
    asio::cancellation_signal some_cancellation;
};

Minimal Demo
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

using data = std::array<char, 1024>;

struct my_object : /*public*/  std::enable_shared_from_this<my_object> {
    using socket_type   = tcp::socket;
    using executor_type = socket_type::executor_type;

    explicit my_object(auto ex) : socket_(make_strand(ex)) {}

    void my_api() {
        post(socket_.get_executor(), //
             asio::bind_cancellation_slot(some_cancellation.slot(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
                 for (auto& ch : some_data)
                     ch += 1;
             }));
    }

    void cancel() { some_cancellation.emit(asio::cancellation_type::terminal); }

    executor_type get_executor() { return socket_.get_executor(); }
  private:
    socket_type               socket_;
    data                      some_data;
    asio::cancellation_signal some_cancellation;
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<my_object>> objects;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        auto& obj = objects.emplace_back(std::make_shared<my_object>(ioc.get_executor()));
        obj->my_api();
        obj->my_api();
        obj->my_api();
    }

    for (auto& obj : objects)
        obj->cancel();

    ioc.join();
}


I recently answered another question that had similar "detached" operations and lifetime issues, where I did try to shoe-horn it with use_future like your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78448518/segmentation-fault-boostasiodetailepoll-reactorrun/78451924#78451924 (in order to stay close to the question code). I think that code subtly depends on the timer interval being "significant". I vastly prefer explicit lifetime management as in this answer, which is reasonably close to the question code as well.


you should flip it around: Keep my_object alive as long as the work still needs to complete. The most common method is shared_from_this.


so, this is the "traditional" ASIO advice and exactly what I *don't* want to do and what I'm refering to in my post when I say "why it seems to fight so hard against the concept of encapsulation". I think that it's bad design that a library implementation enforces lifetime considerations on parent objects that may for what it's worth hide ASIO entirely as an implementation detail.

e.g. what if I want to use ASIO in the context of a framework for which I don't control the object's lifetimes?

I fail to see why enable_shared_from_this is at odds with encapsulation (on the contrary!). Of course, you can always actually move the context into your object, like I did with this recent answer also about interval-timed-tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78314381/how-to-call-different-methods-with-their-own-sample-intervals-inside-a-class-usi#comment138139948_78320738 - to me that is the definition of giving the user choice: nothing assumes anything about the nature of the execution context or scheduler.

@Jean-MichaëlCelerier "e.g. what [...] I don't control the object's lifetimes?" - Then you control what you can control: the lifetimes of async operations. If this means extra buffer copying, so be it. I tend to think that's more of a design issue with the framework than with Asio, but I guess it can be dependent on POV.

@sehe I believe obj->cancel(); introduces potential data race, since cancellation_signal itself is not thread-safe entity and your asynchronous operations are executed in thread_pool. I think you have to implement my_object::cancel via posting/dispatching signal emission to socket's executor(which is gonna be strand)
From documentation: "When emitting a cancellation signal, the thread safety rules apply as if calling a member function on the target operation's I/O object. ... "
